# Can't boot Ubuntu 17.10: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer

Tags: boot, 17.10, acpi

I can't boot Ubuntu 17.10

```
[    7.872529] tmp_crb MFST0101:00:
[Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer.
[mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80
```

There are two lines like that.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you only just installed Ubuntu or is this a new problem with an installation you have had for a while? What hardware is this on? Please [edit] your question to add information

Comment: [An Asus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/422454/209677)? Could you edit adding the output of `inxi -SM -! 31 && grep acpi /etc/default/grub`?

Answer (score 1):

[Seems to be a BIOS bug](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9585671/).

Try to switch off [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) and ACPI in the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your system BIOS to the latest version. 17.10 seems to be having problems. Try updating your system BIOS or stick to the 16.04 LTS and update to 18.04 LTS which would be rolling out in a few months.

Comment: Latest BIOS version, fast boot disabled and I still get the same issue.

Comment: I'm suddenly experiencing this on a System76 Meerkat running Pop! 21.04.