# Ubuntu isn't booting up after installing 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, acpi, firmware

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 in my dell 5567 laptop and after installing it is just showing a black screen when I select Ubuntu in the GRUB menu. I have noticed some errors while restarting the system after installation. The errors are showing that hardware error and also `firmware bug : ACPI region does not cover the entire command`.

When I choose *Try Ubuntu*, it is opening and I can use Ubuntu like that. Why is it not opening after I installed the OS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: No... Even after adding nomodeset, it is showing a black screen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot Ubuntu 17.10: \[Firmware Bug\]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007118/cant-boot-ubuntu-17-10-firmware-bug-acpi-region-does-not-cover-the-entire-c)

Comment: No... Even the bug was there in Ubuntu 18.04 and it was opening