# PC Won't Boot Ubuntu (or any OS)

Tags: startup, bios

I currently can't boot my PC (I can power it on and get to BIOS screens and such, but can't boot an OS). I'm running Ubuntu and don't currently have a Windows partition on it. When I boot, I end up on a black screen with the following (I left out a little bit of text that I didn't seem was necessary but can put the rest in if I need to):

*DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR, contact BIOS vendor for fixes*

*x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS*

*tmp_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer.*

*tmp_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer.*

*/dev/sda3: recovering journal*

*/dev/sda3: clean, 220751/61022208 files, 7545339/244058624 blocks*

*mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)*

It then just stays on this screen indefinitely. Looking for a solution to at least get started up. I don't use this computer for anything important, primarily just to remote in to my office computer and very basic web browsing, so I have no problem with formatting hard drives and losing any data on it if necessary.

If I try to boot from a flash drive, it takes me to a black screen that just says "Grub" and starts beeping.

It is an Alienware X51 R3 with BIOS v1.2.15 (which appears to be the most recent).

Comment: Are you using Safe Boot in live installer? What version of Ubuntu. Are drives RAID? You need at least 22.04. I think all those messages are comments. Most we have checked and they are not an issue.

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to trigger safe boot for live installer. Ubuntu is v22.04 I believe. I don't know if the drives are RAID or how to tell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot Ubuntu 17.10: \[Firmware Bug\]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007118/cant-boot-ubuntu-17-10-firmware-bug-acpi-region-does-not-cover-the-entire-c)